# mount points space reorganization

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my PC. I could see following output for "df -h" command.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9        95G   88G  2.5G  98% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  956K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            3.9G  8.6M  3.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda7        92M   56M   32M  65% /boot
```

My doubht here is, it is showing 3.9GB allocated for /dev and /run/shm, is it really required 3.9GB for those mount points.
I can reduce the size for those mount points and allocate space to root(/).

Comment: The `/dev` and `/run/shm` mount points are system created and represent space reserved for OS operation, not physical space on your drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are virtual filesystems. They do not consume space from any disk device. The number 3.9G is arbitrary and have nothing to do with storage. So no, you cannot reallocate that space to root.

In fact, I would guess that your hard drive was sold as "100 GB" which is hard drive vendor lies for `100 000 000 000 bytes = 93 GB`. If that is the case your hard drive is in the neighbourhood of 102 000 000 000 bytes since they might have given you some extra for free.

Comment: Actually it is dual boot. I think while installing Ubuntu admin has allocated 100GB for Ubuntu.